# Angular2 rc4 ngModelChange onchange instead of keypress

Tags: angular

I'm sure this is possible but I haven't seen it in the documentation.

I want something() to fire below upon the input's onchange event, 
not every time a key is pressed. like how knockout does it by default.

```
<input [ngModel]="whatever" (ngModelChange)="something($event)">
```

I know I can debounce the keystrokes but I'm hoping to avoid that.
thanks!

Comment: I ended up making an input component that uses (change) and (blur) and then compares the model version to the initial version and fires eventemitter if there's a difference...and it has to account for (change) and (blur) often firing back-to-back, so it's quite a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a local template variable to pass the new value:

```
<input #input [ngModel]="whatever" (change)="something(input.value)">
<br>{{whatever}}
```

Then update the model if appropriate in the event handler:

```ts
something(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
  this.whatever = newValue;  // maybe conditionally update this
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about (change) and (blur) (i had to use both of them to get it to work), i was just hoping there was an angular2 ngModelChangeStrategy or something where it could be set to keypress or change or whatever (a la knockout)

Comment: @mookietheswede, I'm not aware of any way to change the  ngModelChange behavior.